# Trying to determine which use cases in my diagram qualify as primary use cases

Tags: uml, use-case

I am designing a UML use case diagram for an event planning app. The home page allows the user to choose which list they would like to view.

- View Venues
- View Productions
- View Special Events

Each presents a list of their respective entities, allowing you to select from the list to view a page with more details of that entity.

At first I had each 'View' use case as a primary entity, because the user must select a list from the home page, but then realized that since the user is responsible for both selecting a list to view AND selecting something to view from that list, nearly every single use case in my diagram (this is basically the extent of the apps functionality) may qualify as a primary use case, and therefore must associate back to the user actor. Is that the case? Because it seems like that would make my diagram a mess. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are, like so many others, seduced to do functional decomposition on use cases. That's not the goal. Use cases are about added values of a system under consideration. There is no "primary use case". A use case shows a single added value. Nothing else.

Looking at `Retrieve Details`, that's no use case at all since it does not deliver any added value to any actor.  `Retrieve Details` is just a function in a scenario in some use case.

I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases.